# How can I pass the selected Items from the autocomplete checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, forms, autocomplete, react-hooks, react-forms

I want to save the selected Items into a file. Why this code doesn't work?
Here there is the function that saves data:

```
 const onSubmitChecked = (selectedRoles, file) => {
    const fileData = JSON.stringify(selectedRoles);
    const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: "text/plain" });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = `${file}.json`;
    link.href = url;
    link.click();
  };
```

Here there is the checkbox:

```
<AutoComplete
          multiple
          id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
          options={props.roles}
          disableCloseOnSelect
          getOptionLabel={(options) => `${options}`}
          renderOption={(options, { selected }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <Checkbox
                icon={icon}
                checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                style={{ marginRight: 20 }}
                checked={selected}
              />
              {props.roles}
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
          style={{ width: 500 }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              variant="outlined"
              label=""
              placeholder="Available Roles"
            />
          )}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmitChecked}>
          Save
        </button>
```

But when I run this code I get the following error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLButtonElement'
|     property '__reactFiber$l9vrne8ayg' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
--- property 'stateNode' closes the circle